# Project Explorer view in a pure Eclipse4 application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

Is it possible to add "Project Explorer View" to a pure Eclipse 4 application, ie, with no Compatibility Layer?

I spent the last two days studying several tutorials (like [this one](http://dirksmetric.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/tutorial-eclipse-rcp-e4-with-3-x-views-like-project-explorer-properties-etc/) and also [this one](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4MigrationGuide/article.html)) but I could not find anything useful regarding this.

One year after Eclipse 4 release, mixing old and new components is still hard, unsupported and looks meaningless. (sigh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't yet mix views that use the 3.x APIs (like the Project Explorer) and Eclipse4 applications without the 4.x Workbench (compat layer).

One of the plans for Luna (June 2014) includes starting to decouple the workbench views (like Progress view, error log, etc) so they can be used in Eclipse4 applications.